# Webview height is not being update?

Tags: android, webview

> I am working on a HTML book reader so in web-view i am loading the
>   webpages .Here i am having zoom in and zoom-out buttons so on
>   clicking of zoom-in i am increasing the web view parameters i.e Width
>   and Height but my problem is that after changing the params the height
>   parameters is not updates that meaning it do not comes to the new
>   given height .Specially in case of zoom out it show the previous
>   height itself but width works OK and content also shrink.It will not
>   update the height until any click event happens if i click on some
>   buttons or moves to the next page it comes properly.
>
> So my main problem is that in case of zoom out the web view height
>   parameter is not set properly ,please suggest me
>           any    way.
>               i called invalidate() also after the layout parameter changes but not
>              working so please tell me any workable solution and thanks in advance.

Comment: Somehow similar problem but no workable answer-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669724/layout-height-doesnt-update-until-another-event-is-triggered/13956165#comment20168642_13956165

Comment: invalidate() causes the view to redraw itself. You want requestLayout() which causes the view to remeasure itself and layout.

Comment: @user123321 tried but not working

Comment: @user123321 thanks but it is also not working

Comment: Maybe you've solved your problem, but if you haven't, you can try to look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946295/android-expand-collapse-animation).
 Sorry if that's not what you are looking for and sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15687522/1228514